# Radiation of accelerated Charge: Impact on macroscopic objects

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, charge, acceleration

Accelerated charge obeys an energy loss due to radiation. This is one reason why the classical picture of electrons orbiting the nucleus would result in a non-stable atom since the electrons would collapse into the nucleus due to the energy loss. The acceleration of the orbiting charge is the centripetal acceleration in this case.

So, let us scale up this microscopic problem into our macroscopic world.

At first, I would assume that a macroscopic object, say a space ship that leaves our solar system, would not slow down over time because the space ship moves with a constant velocity (when we assume that there would be not centripetal or any other acceleration).

However, would an object like a planet theoretically slow down due to radiation of accelerated charge? The earth is orbiting the sun, so there is centripetal acceleration (I guess there are also other effects that could slow down the planet over time, but I would like to focus on this effect here). I would assume that the superposition of all electric fields from all electrons and nucleus on earth would almost cancel out, hence there is no radiation of any accelerated electric field.

Answer (score 3):

The "far field" of an accelerated charged particle, which falls as $1/r$, is nearly, but not completely, cancelled by the far field of a nearby oppositely charged particle undergoing the same motion. The reason why they don't cancel perfectly is that the vector from the first particle to the observation point and the vector from the second particle to the observation point are not exactly equal, so the fields won't be exactly equal and opposite.

As a result, a dipole made up of two oppositely charged particles still radiates when accelerated, but not as much as either particle would if alone. A quadrupole made up of two dipoles with equal and opposite dipole moments would accelerate even less, and so on. To be specific, if the $2^\ell$-pole moment is the lowest order one that changes as a body undergoes accelerated motion, the far fields are suppressed by a factor proportional to $(v/c)^\ell$ where $v$ is the "average" velocity of the body during the acceleration. That means the radiated power is suppressed by $(v/c)^{2\ell}$.

A body whose multipole moments vanish to all orders—namely, a neutral body whose internal charge distribution is spherically symmetric—does not emit electromagnetic radiation as a result of its accelerated motion. It still emits gravitational radiation, though, which is much weaker.